# What happens if you press Shift + Apple + 4 in Windows?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I´m running Windows 7 on my Macbook. Accidently I pressed a weird key combination: Shift + Apple + 4. It didn´t make a screenshot but instead i just starts a random application. What exactly is happening here?

Comment: Does the Apple key work like the Windows key would in Windows?  If that,'s the case, Win + # launches the corresponding app pinned to your taskbar.  (Not making this an answer yet because hey, I don't know if it does.)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it listed [in this wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts) ?

> Open new program window of the pinned program on the taskbar (if program is already opened)
>
> ⊞ Win+⇧ Shift+(#) where "#" is the position of the program on the Windows 7 Taskbar (Windows 7 only)

Comment: The program isn´t in the taskbar. It just starts some randomly exes.

Comment: Hum... perhaps it lauches the 4th most-recently used program ? And since that program is them moved to the top of the list, next time the 4th program is another one ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if the Apple key gets converted to <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>, Looking it up seems to state different things depending on the keyboard you are using.

In any way, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> is application dependent (e.g. In Chrome, switches to the 4th tab)

Excluding this, various combinations of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> all do operations on the 4th pinned item on the Windows Task bar.

Operations include launching 4th pinned item, switching between the 4th item's open window and launching the 4th item's context menu.